# How to hide an addon Ribbon until we want to display it using Outlook 2013 and C#?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm developing a commercial application and I need to setup an authentication in Outlook. A panel use for connection in outlook trigger a server check with an API. But, this panel is display in my ThisAddin code file. However, my addin Ribbon is handle in another file (ACF_Ribbon). I want to hide this Ribbon until the user is authenticated by my panel, then display it if the authentication is done successfully.

Anyone can have a solution ? I found nothing in the MSDN for Outlook.

UPDATE & PARTIAL ANSWER :

As far as I have search, it's nearly impossible using the Ribbon designer due to the fact that  the management of the Ribbon is done automaticly.So my actual solution is to disable all button while the authentification isn't done. That's not a solution, but could help if someone have the same matter than me.

Comment: Adding things like *it is urgent* feels like giving the other users a task to accomplish. As you aren't hiring us to do work this may have the effect that nobody will help you. The question should be able to stand on its own (and it seems to me that it does).

Comment: Sure, was just a useless detail. Get removed by halfer (thanks for the correction)

Answer (score 0):

Your ribbon must specify the getVisible callback pointing to your function. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633442%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more details.

Comment: I'm trying but it seems that this solution is avaible for XML Ribbon only. I get mine by using the Ribbon designer. Have you a code exemple using it ? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Ribbon Designer ultimately outputs the XML too - Outlook does not know or care how your XML was produced. That being said, I don't use the designer, so I don't know.

Comment: Okay, that's sad because I can't actually parse the designer into a XML in my project, I have to keep it like this. do you have an idea about another way to deal with ?